# NullPointerException error in a for loop

Tags: java, android, arrays, exception

I have this method and every time i try to put value in my `foo` array i get NullPointerException. I tried to solve it but i dont know why it tells me NullPointerException.
Thank for helping :)

```
mine = " 0 2 3 ";

    try {                       
        for(int i = 0; i < mine.length(); i++) {
            String k = "" + mine.charAt(i);
            if(k.equals(" ") == false)
                j++;    
        }
    } catch(Exception r) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    try {
        int[] foo = new int[j];

        for(int i = 0; i < mine.length(); i++) {    
            String k = "" + mine.charAt(i);
            if(k.equals(" ") == false) {
                String a = "" + mine.charAt(i); 
                myNum = Integer.parseInt(a);
                foo[i-1] = myNum;
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception df) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: *Where* do you get the exception. Note that you'll run into trouble if you execute `foo[i-1] = myNum;` when `i` is 0...

Comment: Also if i>j, which can be the case if there are spaces anywhere...

Comment: While we're at it-  why are you ever creating String k?  What you want is if(mine.charAt(i) == ' ') and not use string.equals or a temporary string there at all.

Answer (score 0):

1. What is `mine`?  if it is null you get a null pointer exception.
2. use meaningful varaible names.  `j` is not meaningful.
3. learn how to compare characters.
4. I suggest using NM style bracing, but that is a personal preference.
5. learn how to use java collections.
6. learn how to access an array by index.  i starts at 0, 0 - 1 is out of bounds.
7. if you are going to use arrays that are not in sync (foo values are not at the same index as mine values), use 2 index variables (perhaps mineIndex and fooIndex).
8. catch exceptions by name.  do not just catch Exception.  if you insist on catching Exception, consider adding this comment: "// I suck at programming" to you catch blocks.

### Option 1

```
List valueList = new LinkedList();
try
{
  for (int index = 0, index < mine.length(); ++ index)
  {
    final char current = mine.charAt(index);

    if (current != ' ')
    {
      valueList.add(Integer.valueOf(current));
    }
  }
}
catch (NullPointerException exception)
{
  ... do something.
}
catch (NumberFormatExxception exception)
{
  ... do something.
}
```

### Option 2 - this is terrible

```
int valueCount = 0;
try
{
  for (int index = 0, index < mine.length(); ++ index)
  {
    if (mine.getAt(index) != ' ')
    {
      ++valueCount;
    }
  }
}
catch (NullPointerException exception)
{
  ... do something.
}

if (valueCount > 0)
{
  try
  {
    int[] foo = new int[valueCount];
    int valueIndex = 0;

    for (int index = 0, index < mine.length(); ++ index)
    {
      final char current = mine.charAt(index);

      if (current != ' ')
      {
        foo[valueIndex++] = Integer.valueOf(current));
      }
    }
  }
  catch (NullPointerException exception)
  {
    ... do something.
  }
  catch (NumberFormatExxception exception)
  {
    ... do something.
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. mine isnt null. 2. equal() method dont let me to compare Char for some reason and i dont have power to look why so i created temporay string.